# How to prevent black boxes on desktop icons in Windows after removing shortcut arrows?

Tags: icons, desktop-customization, debug, regedit, desktop-icons

When removing shortcut arrows using the regedit value

```
%windir%\System32\shell32.dll,-50
```

in `Shell Icons` `29`, black boxes cover up my desktop icons where the shortcut arrows used to be.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Which OS is this happening to?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following value in regedit

```
%windir%\System32\shell32.dll,-50
```

is a transparent icon in `shell32.dll` (in this case value `-50`). Using any of these values to remove shortcut arrows in `shell32.dll` will corrupt the `IconCache.db` file located in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local`. This can temporarily be fixed by deleting `IconCache.db` and restarting or logging off and on your computer. However, the black boxes will come back because Windows continues to corrupt `IconCache.db` each time it tries to overwrite it with value `-50` in `shell32.dll`.

To **permanently** fix the problem without using 3rd party software, do this...

Download this [blank.ico](http://www.deskmodder.de/.moinmoin/Wiki-Deskmodder/Blank.ico.zip) and save it somewhere on your `C: drive`.

For example,

`C:\Users\UserName\Pictures\Desktop Icons`.

Then use this value instead of `%windir%\System32\shell32.dll,-50` in `Shell Icons` value `29` in regedit (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`) like this:

```
C:\Users\UserName\Pictures\Desktop Icons\blank.ico
```

This will use the `blank.ico` file on your `C: drive` instead of accessing the transparent icon files on `shell32.dll` and your `IconCache.db` will no longer be corrupted, removing the black boxes and the shortcut arrows forever.

For those who want steps on how to do this in regedit, reading material can be found here on [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-shortcut-icon-arrow-overlay-in-windows-vista/).

Comment: BTW. I've done this technique and it seems to work for a while. But the black boxes will come back. If you leave the field totally empty you wont have the black box problem. But every once in a while all your icons will dissapear for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Create key "Shell Icons", Add String Value and name it "29", add this text to the string value:  %windir%\System32\shell32.dll,-50 and reboot.

If the shortcut arrow box is black then delete the text in the string value named 29 and then reboot. The arrow and the black box will be gone.

Ron

Comment: `shell32.dll-50` causes the problem of black boxes appearing over the icons. You'll need to use a transparent .ico file instead. [Shortcut Icons Covered with White Icons or Black Boxes Overlay](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-overlapping-icon-windows-7-vista/)

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. It's a temporary fix. Making the entire 29 string field empty will last longer. But every once in a while your icons will all disappear and you won't know why. That's why. Change that back or delete 29 and it will fix the Icon Vanishing problem.